# Finding attribute option value between configurable product and its simple products by sql query

Tags: database, configurable-product, magento2.4, configurable-product-options

Using Magento 2.4
MaySql 8

I am investing now a lot of time to try finding the option_id (red marked) of the connected simple product to the configurable products.

[image]

I ended up in the following tables:
`catalog_product_relation`  -> this gives me relation from `parent_id` to `child_id`
`catalog_product_super_attribute`
`catalog_product_super_link`

following the parent id and searching for it in  `catalog_product_super_attribute`  gives me the attribute_id that corresponds to the correct attribute. So far so good.

[image]

But when I would like to check which simple product has the real `option_value` set I don´t know how to go on.

The shop is currently broken down and we need to get out the products by sql and not by php or api.I am searching for the connection from these tables to option id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding attribute option value between configurable product and its simple products by sql query](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/370912/finding-attribute-option-value-between-configurable-product-and-its-simple-produ)

Comment: actually it was a duplicated